# How do you delay form submission (to google sheets) so that it can be validated first by a script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I'm working on a website and I am able to properly submit information from my form to google sheets by following this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xV4duATsvfs&t=1s.
However, when I tried to submit the form with an empty field to test the validation script I'm using (https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation), they both simultaneously run. In other words, it does check the field but it also submits it right away along with the empty fields resulting in an empty cell in the google sheets.

Comment: I'd probably try overriding the form submission behavior with jquery and use AJAX to submit after the validation script has run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case .I suggest you use jquery submit to deal with it.
First ,You chould define your form rule via  jquery-validation,then use jquery submit function to submit the form .

something like

```
<script>
    $("#submitButton").click(function() {
        var  validator  =  $("#myform").validate({
            rules:  { /*your rules*/ },
            messages:  { /*your messages*/ },
            invalidHandler:   function () {
                /*invalidHandler*/
            }
        })
        if(validator){$("#myform").submit();}
    });
</script>
```

Hope this help you :)

Comment: here is my example to explain the concept
https://jsfiddle.net/Not2Day2Die/v81jx03L/